# Error page displayed after submiting form in Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress

I have a wordpress site, in which there is a form where the user gives the username and after submitting it he/she is being redirected to another page. In this page some user related data from the database is being displayed. I am trying to create a search form, which will display only the data related to the input of the form, like year or something.

Here is the code for the original form:

```
add_action('init', function () {
   $username = ( isset($_POST['luname']) ? $_POST['luname'] : '' );
   setcookie("usernameCookie", $username, time()+3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
   if ($username) {
       setcookie("usernameCookie", $username, time()+3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
   }

   if( isset( $_POST['mysubmitbtn'] ) ) {
       wp_redirect('http://mysite/somedata/');
       exit;
   }
});
```

Here is the code in the page where user is being redirected to :

```
<?php

$s=$_COOKIE["usernameCookie"] ;
if ( username_exists( $s ) ) { 
    global $wpdb;
    echo "<b>user: ".$s."</b>";
    echo 
    '<form method="post" name="myForm">
        <input type="number" name="year" placeholder="Search Year"/>
    </form>';

    if( isset( $_POST['year'] ) && is_numeric($_POST['year']) ) { 
        $year = $_POST['year'];

        $results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("Select * From mytable Where user_login = %s and year = %d", $s, $year)); 
        foreach ( $results as $result ) { 
            $pdf = $result->pdfId;
            echo 
                '<div style="text-align: left;"><br>
                    <a style="text-decoration: underline; text-decoration-color: #a83252;" href="http://testingforwordpress.epizy.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/pdf'.$pdf.'.pdf" download="law'.$pdf.'.pdf">
                    <h5 style="font-family: Arial; color: #a83252;">'.$result->law.'</h5></a>
                    <span style="font-family: Arial;">'.$result->description.'</span>
                </div>'; 
        }
    }
    else {
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("Select * From mytable Where user_login = %s", $s)); 

        foreach ( $results as $result) { 
            $pdf = $result->pdfId;
            echo 
            '<div style="text-align: left;"><br>
                <a style="text-decoration: underline; text-decoration-color: #a83252;" href="http://testingforwordpress.epizy.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/pdf'.$pdf.'.pdf" download="law'.$pdf.'.pdf">
                <h5 style="font-family: Arial; color: #a83252;">'.$result->law.'</h5></a>
                <span style="font-family: Arial;">'.$result->description.'</span>
            </div>'; 
        } 
    } 
}
else echo '
<h3 style="text-align: center; color: red;">Username '.$s.' does not exist.</h3>';

?>
```

In mytable I have a column "year" and some values like 2019, 0, 2015 in different rows. The problem is that this works only if i press 2019 or 0 in the form, if i press 2015 a theme message is being displayed "This page doesn't seem to exist. It looks like the link pointing here was faulty. Maybe try searching?" with a search bar below. If i change the year value from 2015 to 2019 the row is being displayed normally. It's like there's something wrong with the query that i don't understand. I tried changing it, but the problem persists. Can someone offer a solution to this?

Comment: Every possible combination of removing/adding certain code was done...still

Comment: Created another page and used Ajax instead